# Cannot use `static_assert` with `sizeof` inside class scope (but method scope is okay)

Tags: c++, g++

Here's an excerpt from a simple example (see the [full source live here](http://ideone.com/A83qig)):

```
class Foo final {
    public:
        int var;

        inline Foo(void) {
            static_assert(sizeof(Foo)==sizeof(int),"Implementation error!");
        }

        static_assert(sizeof(Foo)==sizeof(int),"Implementation error!");
};
```

On a recent g++ (N.B. MSVC doesn't complain), this produces something like:

> error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘Foo’

That error occurs *only* on the second `static_assert`.

I understand that the class's definition hasn't finished being written out *lexically*, but surely all the information for a complete type is there, right?  I mean, we're *inside* the thing.  And even if not, why would it work in the method?

Comment: I'm not sure of chapter and verse, but inline method bodies are not "compiled" beyond the most basic parsing until after the class definition has been processed . Otherwise they couldn't access member variables whose declarations are lower down, etc.

Comment: @MattMcNabb So this strange behaviour is due to 'inline'?

Comment: @MattMcNabb added the `inline` reflexively. Without `inline` is identical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class type is complete inside its own member function bodies (as Matt says, processing of the function bodies is deferred).  It's not complete in most other places inside the `{}` of the class definition, including that `static_assert`.  The rule from section 9.2 is

> A  class  is  considered  a  completely-defined  object  type (or  complete  type)  at  the  closing  `}`  of  the *class-specifier*.  Within the class *member-specification*, the class is regarded as complete within function
>   bodies, default arguments, *using-declarations* introducing inheriting constructors (12.9), *exception-specifications*, and
>   *brace-or-equal-initializers* for non-static data members (including such things in nested classes).  Otherwise it is regarded as incomplete within its own class *member-specification*.

Think about it for a minute, how should the compiler know that you don't have

```
int another_var;
```

coming right after the `static_assert`?

The best place for the `static_assert` is probably right after the class definition, in namespace scope.

Comment: Well, it seems quite strange to me. I always used to think that those 'forward' rules are applied to pure C only.

Comment: Re the best place for a static_assert: this question was simplified from a problem I'm having with a templated class. I don't suppose there's a slick way to do that outside the class bounds?